# WWE 2k22 for PS4 not loading on my PS5

Tags: ps4, ps5, wwe-2k22

Today WWE 2k22 PS4 version got added into PS Plus catalogue

1. Downloaded the game
2. created account
3. accepted terms and conditions
4. selected play -> one on one -> normal -> selected characters -> started the match

After above steps it is getting stuck on loading screen on my PS5, whole screen is black.
Also, why only one on one battle available with normal mode and few characters?

solutions tried

1. restarted my PS5 several times
2. deleted the game and reinstalled it
3. tried to close the game several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the game was not completely downloaded and it was not showing it anywhere on playstation screen that the game is still downloading.
I did some research and found this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KshP2k9gSpY)
above youtube video is for ps4 for ps5 to check this game is fully downloaded or not you have to press playstation button then there is one menu option Downloads/Uploads. when you select that menu it will show you how much time remaining to download the game completely.